# surefire-report behavior in multi-module project with DnoTest=true

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a multimodule maven project

```
<modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
    <module>C</module>
    <module>D</module>
</modules>
```

`B` depends on `A` and `C` depends on `B`. I do not want to execute unit tests on `A` & `D`.

So I have added `skipTest` like below in module `A`:-

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${mvn.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If I execute the below two maven commands:-

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests -T 6 
mvn surefire-report:report -DnoTest=true
```

Will `D` be compiled and build again in `surefire-report` phase or just `A`, `B` & `C` be compiled and their test will be executed?

If yes then is there a way I can prevent the compiling of `D` in surefire phase as I don't want to execute tests on `D`?

I am using `maven 3.2.x`.